# Android Studio - How to put Buttons in a ListView

Tags: android, button, android-listview

I have a problem. I want to put Buttons in a listview but I don't know how to do that. I searched a lot but I found nothing. The major problem is to have a button for each elements of the ListView. I think I have to precise that I'm a very beginner so If it's really hard I will not understand very well.

NB: Sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: You might consider using a ```recyclerView```,  it also comes with animations and you can design it beautifully with whatever elements you want also buttons

Comment: I suggest that you back up a little. Do you know how to add several `TextView`s to a `ListView`? If not, figure that out first. Then figure out what to do from there.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can do that, I searched and I found how to do it. Finally, It's very simple. I just have to put the textview in the Listview then just include android:onClick="onClick" in the textview and it works.